VS Code and Gulp 5.0 / Gulp Cli 3.0

I´m trying to copy some files between folders without success.
This is my program:
const gulp  = require('gulp');
const using = require('gulp-using')
const fs = require('fs');
const gzip = require('gulp-gzip');
const flatmap = require('gulp-flatmap');
const path = require('path');
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
const cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const pump = require('pump');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin-changba');
const gulpCopy = require('gulp-copy');

exports.default =  function() {
   
    return gulp.src('../front/assets/img/*.*', {encoding: false})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
   

    }

If I run a gulp on the terminal I get the following error:
[09:14:07] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\ESP32 Config Tools\webBuilder\gulpfile.js
[09:14:07] Starting 'default'...
[09:14:07] The following tasks did not complete: default
Did you forget to signal async completion?`

When I change the function to async as below, it runs but no files are copied.
exports.default = async function() {
   
    return gulp.src('../front/assets/img/*.*', {encoding: false})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
   

    }

[09:22:08] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\webBuilder\gulpfile.js
[09:22:08] Starting 'default'...
[09:22:08] Finished 'default' after 11 ms

If I change the src to copy only one file (by name), it works with or without async and copies the file from the src to the destination
exports.default =  function() {
   
    return gulp.src('../front/assets/img/logo.png', {encoding: false})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
   

    }`
result: 
[09:23:36] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\webBuilder\gulpfile.js
[09:23:36] Starting 'default'...
[09:23:36] Finished 'default' after 26 ms

exports.default = async function() {
   
    return gulp.src('../front/assets/img/favicon.png', {encoding: false})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
   

    }
[09:24:52] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\webBuilder\gulpfile.js
[09:24:52] Starting 'default'...
[09:24:52] Finished 'default' after 10 ms`

files on folder dist:
[enter image description here][1]

I found this solution, but have the same results (wiyh async runs and dont copy the files, without async got the error Did you forget to signal sync completion?)
const fs = require("fs");


gulp.task('default', function (callback) {
    try {
        fs.copyFile("./img/background.jpg", "./image/background.jpg", callback);
    } catch (e) {
        // nth
    }
});

what am I doing wrong?
My OS is Windows 10 Home, 22H2, OS comp.: 19045.4529
Copy files between folders

I downgraded to version 4.0.2 and it worked. If anyone knows how to do this in V5, post here
